# When I use a PHP page to edit a jqGrid data, what's kind of data that the PHP page has to return as result of the updating?

Tags: php, jqgrid

I'm using a PHP page to update the data when I edit them in the jqGrid (using the parameter "editurl").

```
$("#campionati").jqGrid({
    url: "dbread.php",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames: ["ID", "Nome", "Descrizione", "URL"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "id", width: 16, align: 'center'},
        {name: "nome", width: 90, align: 'right', editable: true},
        {name: "descrizione", width: 80, editable: true},
        {name: "url", width: 600, editable: true, formatter: 'link', formatoptions: {target: '_blank'}}
    ],
    editurl: "dbwrite.php?action=updateCampionati",
    pager: "#pager",

    ...
```

It works.

My question is: what's kind of data that my PHP page has to return to tell to jqGrid if the update has been successful or not?

```
<php

...

echo 0;
```

or

```
<php

...

echo json_encode(array("result" => "OK"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important the [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) of the server response. You code seems to return the status code 200 OK. So the response will be interpreted as successful. To return information about the error one can use [http_response_code](http://php.net/manual/de/function.http-response-code.php) for example.